# Cufon current menu item doens't work in IE7

Tags: internet-explorer-7, menuitem, cufon

I've tried to define the hover and .current class state within cufon.

Now I'm trying to get cufon to work in IE7 but the code I've created seems to give a error.
IE8 & IE9 seem to get it but IE7 doesn't...

Can anyone give me a tip on what's going wrong in my coding

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        Cufon('ul#mainMenu li.current a', {
            color: '#5a3b10',
            textShadow: '1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)',
        });

        Cufon.replace('h1');
        Cufon.replace('h2');
        Cufon.replace('h3');
        Cufon.replace('h4');
        Cufon.replace('h5');
        Cufon.replace('h6');
        Cufon.replace('ul#mainMenu li a', {
            hover: {
            color: '#5a3b10',
            textShadow: '1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)',
            }
        });

        Cufon.replace('ul#mainMenu li.current a', {
            color: '#5a3b10',
            textShadow: '1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)',
    }); 
}); 
</script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem with IE7. Are you using/loading jQuery as well? If yes, then just make sure that the JS for jQuery loads first. Then load the JS for the Cufon. I did this and my issue solved in an instant. Let me know if this helps.